# Flutter set value to a textfield

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I have a project with a list of contacts (name, phone, address), when the user taps on contact I'm sending him to an edit form, I want to fill the form with the contact data.
I'm using a Textfield for the inputs and getting data through widgets using for example: widget.contact.data['name'].
I couldn't find any answers for this problem.

Comment: Show some codes. Can use a TextEditingController to add items though.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two ways to access text from a TextField, as shown in Flutter's [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes).

The first one is through the onChanged callback, which has a parameter that is the current text.

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text) {
    // do what you want with the text
  },
);
```

For more advanced handling of the text, including accessing it from outside the `build()` method, you can use [TextEditingController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html).

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Then you can link it to your TextField:

```
TextField(
  // other parameters
  controller: _controller,
);
```

Don't forget to dispose it!

```
@override
void dispose() {
  // other dispose methods
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Now you can either set or get the text by either accessing the value of `_controller.text` or modifying it. For example:

Getting: `print(_controller.text);`

Setting: `_controller.text = 'newText' // now the TextField will have 'newText' written`

Or you can listen to changes using `addListener`, so whenever the text is updated, a function of your choice will be called:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_handleText);
    // other code here
}

_handleText() {
   // do what you want with the text, for example:
   print(_controller.text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I used the TextEditingController, on the initState I loaded the controllers with the values from the list of contacts, that solve my problem.

Comment: @RafaelHonda If this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the tick mark. Check this link for more details -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers